# fetching particuler data from curl response

Tags: php, regex, curl, explode

i am using curl and php for login a website .
curl response is:-

```
41~BAIL/37246/2013~101~ILYAS~STATE OF U.P.~D~12:46:41 08/01/2014|44~A482/42266/2012~21~BHIKENDRA VARSHNEY~STATE OF U.P. AND ANOTHER~D~12:46:41 08/01/2014|44~A482/42647/2012~22~BHIKENDRA VARSHNEY~STATE OF U.P. AND ANOTHER~D~12:46:41 08/01/2014|51~BAIL/39156/2013~131~MANSURI ALAM~STATE OF U.P.~F~12:46:41 08/01/2014|52~CRLAD/68/2012~33~JALEES~STATE OF U.P.~D~12:46:41 08/01/2014|54~A482/46798/2013~191~MADHAU SINGH AND 2 ORS.~STATE OF U.P. AND ANOTHER~B~12:46:41 08/01/2014|54~A482/47074/2013~95~S.S.I. R.S.VERMA AND ANOTHER~STATE OF U.P. AND ANOTHER~F~12:46:41 08/01/201
```

i want to split string  after special

```
 | and ~
```

and store data different variables like

```
$a=41,
$b=BAIL/3724/2013,
$dateTime=12:46:41 08/01/2014
```

for later use.thanks

Comment: `print_r(explode('~',$yourresponse));` Try that.

Comment: sir i want to split line both charecter | and ~ and use for loop for retrive value

Comment: [explode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) on `|`, then [sscanf()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sscanf.php) perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

Do like this..

```
<?php
$str='41~BAIL/37246/2013~101~ILYAS~STATE OF U.P.~D~12:46:41 08/01/2014|44~A482/42266/2012~21~BHIKENDRA VARSHNEY~STATE OF U.P. AND ANOTHER~D~12:46:41 08/01/2014|44~A482/42647/2012~22~BHIKENDRA VARSHNEY~STATE OF U.P. AND ANOTHER~D~12:46:41 08/01/2014|51~BAIL/39156/2013~131~MANSURI ALAM~STATE OF U.P.~F~12:46:41 08/01/2014|52~CRLAD/68/2012~33~JALEES~STATE OF U.P.~D~12:46:41 08/01/2014|54~A482/46798/2013~191~MADHAU SINGH AND 2 ORS.~STATE OF U.P. AND ANOTHER~B~12:46:41 08/01/2014|54~A482/47074/2013~95~S.S.I. R.S.VERMA AND ANOTHER~STATE OF U.P. AND ANOTHER~F~12:46:41 08/01/201';

$arrel = explode('|',$str);

foreach($arrel as $val)
{
    $new_el=explode('~',$val);
    echo $new_el[0];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $new_el[1];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $new_el[6];
    echo "<br><br>";

}
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
41
BAIL/37246/2013
12:46:41 08/01/2014

44
A482/42266/2012
12:46:41 08/01/2014

44
A482/42647/2012
12:46:41 08/01/2014

51
BAIL/39156/2013
12:46:41 08/01/2014

52
CRLAD/68/2012
12:46:41 08/01/2014

54
A482/46798/2013
12:46:41 08/01/2014

54
A482/47074/2013
12:46:41 08/01/201
```